# is there a way to index map type column in cassandra

Tags: cassandra, data-modeling, cassandra-3.0, cqlsh

I have a table **susbcriber,** which will contain **millions of data**.

Table schema is as below in cassandra -

```
CREATE TABLE susbcriber (
    id int PRIMARY KEY,
    age_identifier text,
    alternate_mobile_identifier text,
    android_identifier text,
    batch_id text,
    circle text,
    city_identifier text,
    country text,
    country_identifier text,
    created_at text,
    deleted_at text,
    email_identifier text,
    gender_identifier text,
    ios_identifier text,
    list_master_id int,
    list_subscriber_id text,
    mobile_identifier text,
    operator text,
    partition_id text,
    raw_data map<text, text>,
    region_identifier text,
    unique_identifier text,
    updated_at text,
    web_push_identifier text
) WITH bloom_filter_fp_chance = 0.01
    AND caching = {'keys': 'ALL', 'rows_per_partition': 'NONE'}
    AND comment = ''
    AND compaction = {'class': 'org.apache.cassandra.db.compaction.SizeTieredCompactionStrategy', 'max_threshold': '32', 'min_threshold': '4'}
    AND compression = {'chunk_length_in_kb': '64', 'class': 'org.apache.cassandra.io.compress.LZ4Compressor'}
    AND crc_check_chance = 1.0
    AND dclocal_read_repair_chance = 0.1
    AND default_time_to_live = 0
    AND gc_grace_seconds = 0
    AND max_index_interval = 2048
    AND memtable_flush_period_in_ms = 0
    AND min_index_interval = 128
    AND read_repair_chance = 0.0
    AND speculative_retry = '99PERCENTILE';
```

I have to make filter query mostly on `'raw_data map<text, text>,'` this column  contains JSON values and keys, How I can model the data so that **select and update have to be fast in performance** ?

**I am trying to achieve some bulk update operations.**

Any suggestion is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Yeah you can.
Map is used to store dynamic data in table
You can have the index based upon `Keys` ,`Entries` or `values` of a map

There are three options I mentioned below.

If your use case is to search the keys of dynamic data then use first...
if you want to search on the values of **known** key in map then use second...
if you don't know the keys just want to search the values in the map then use third.

```
Create index idx_first on <keyspaceName.tableName> (Keys (<mapColumn>))
Create index idx_second on <keyspaceName.tableName> (Entries (<mapColumn>))
Create index idx_third on <keyspaceName.tableName> (Values (<mapColumn>))
```

Answer (score 1):

If data is already in the map you dont really need to keep the values in their own columns as well, and if its just a key to a map its easier on cassandra to represent it as a clustering key instead of a collection like:

```
CREATE TABLE susbcriber_data (
    id int,
    key text,
    value text,
    PRIMARY KEY((id), key))
```

Then you can query by any id and key. If you are looking where a specific key has a value than

```
CREATE TABLE susbcriber_data_by_value (
    id int,
    shard int,
    key text,
    value text,
    PRIMARY KEY((key, shard), value, id))
```

Then when you insert you set shard to be `id % 12` or some value such that your partitions do not get to large (need to some guessing based on expected load). Then to see all the values where key = value you need to query all 12 of those shards (async call to each and merge). Although if your cardinality for the key/value pairs is low enough the shard might be unnecessary. Then you will have a list of the ids which you can lookup. If you want to avoid the lookup you can add an additional key and value to that table but your data may explode quite a bit depending on the number of keys you have in your map and keeping everything updated will be painful.

An option that I would not recommend but is available is to index the map ie:

```
CREATE INDEX raw_data_idx ON susbcriber ( ENTRIES (raw_data) );

SELECT * FROM susbcriber WHERE raw_data['ios_identifier'] = 'id';
```

Keeping in mind the [issues with secondary indexes](http://www.doanduyhai.com/blog/?p=13191).

Comment: can you make it a little easier to understand, as I am unable to get exactly what I can infer, as in above example raw_data can have more keys(than of table structure keys), and table structure is fixed.

Comment: A more straight forward manual index might be too have the primary key to be simply `((key, value), id)` which would be slightly more efficient for reads but compactions will much slower (which you may not care about). If you want reads as fast as possible a  `((key, value), id, key)` with a `value text` then you can grab a list of subscriptions fully realized in a single read for a given key/value. Updating a value in the subscription will be a pain but the writes are fast and can be done in a single batch if you are ok with disk space usage.